# get uri of realpath

Tags: uri

I want to  create a product(and product display) with below code,everything seem fine ( I did it several time ) but my problem is when I want create image file with ajax posted data, file created correct but when I want attach it to my node I dont know how can I get 'URI' of file?

```
   global $user;
    if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri('public://')) {
  $realpath = $wrapper->realpath();
}
//    print (var_dump(array_keys($_POST)));

//            $_POST['upimages'];
$base64_mainimg=substr($_POST['main'], strpos($_POST['main'], ",")+1);
$base64_mainimgdec = base64_decode($base64_mainimg);
$dir=$realpath.'/'.$user->uid.'/'.arg(1);
if(!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir);         
} 
$mainimg_url = $dir.'/'.time(). '_'.rand(1000,9999).'.jpg';
////create png from decoded base 64 string and save the image in the parent folder
$resultmain = file_put_contents($mainimg_url, $base64_mainimgdec);
$order = commerce_cart_order_load();
    if (!$order) {
        $order = commerce_cart_order_new($user->uid);
    }
    // Save new order to get order id
    if (empty($order->order_id)) {
        $order->revision = FALSE;
        commerce_order_save($order);
    }  
    $order_id = $order->order_id;
    // Wrapper for easy field access and adding line items, order passed by reference
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    $price=  strip_tags($_POST['price']);
    if(intval($price)){
    $product = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', commerce_product_new('gift'));
    $product->title = arg(1).'-'.$user->uid.'-'.time();
    $product->sku = 'CB-'.arg(1).'-'.rand(999999);
    $product->commerce_price->amount = $price*10; // Price in minors units 500 = $5
    $product->commerce_price->currency_code = 'IRR'; // Use your currency... obviously :-)
    $product->status=1;
    $product->save();

    $my_prodcut=commerce_product_load( $product->product_id->value());
    // Create new line item based on selected product
    $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($my_prodcut, 1, $order->order_id);
    // Save new line item to get line item id
    commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
    // Add line item to order wrapper
    $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;
      //$product_display = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',entity_create('node', array('type' => 'flower_display','uid'=>$user->uid)));
      $node = new stdClass(); // Create a new node object
      $node->type = "prodcut_gift_display"; // Or page, or whatever content type you like
      node_object_prepare($node);         
//      $node->field_flowers_ref[]=$samplenode->field_flowers_ref;
      //$node->field_flower_type_cat=$samplenode->field_flower_type_cat;
      //$node->field_image=$samplenode->field_image;
      $uri=file_build_uri($mainimg_url);
      $file = new stdClass;
      $file->uid = $user->uid;
      $file->filename = basename($uri);
      $file->uri = $uri;
      $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($uri);
      $file->filesize = filesize($mainimg_url);
      $file->status = 1;
      file_save($file);
      var_dump($file);
      $node->field_product['und'][0]['product_id']=$my_prodcut->product_id;
      $node->field_gift_image['und'][0]['fid']=$file->fid;
      $node->title=arg(1).'-'.rand(999999);
      $node->language='fa';
//      $node->field_product_code['und'][0]['value']='BF-'.rand(100,999);
//      if($user->uid==1)
//      dsm($node);
      node_save($node);
     }
    $order->revision = FALSE;
    $order_wrapper->save();
```

(with this code very thing is Ok , product and product create correctly but in display of it the image `src` is not correct)
I have `realpath` of file and I try to get uri of it with `$uri=file_build_uri($mainimg_url);` but it is not correct.

**how Can I get uri of file with it's `realpath`?**

Comment: Why not try `$file_uri = file_create_url($mainimg_url);` because file_create_url Creates a web-accessible URL for a stream to an external or local file. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7

Comment: I need uri,but it not return uri for me